# Не работает функция "FORMAT ()" в ms sql

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте, изучаю t-sql. Дошёл до раздела где используется вывод форматированной даты. На одном из официальных сайтов Microsoft [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh213505.aspx) описано как использовать функцию  `FORMAT()`.

Написал такой запрос:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result';
```

Но при выполнении данного скрипта выходит ошибка:

> "Сообщение 195, уровень 15, состояние 10, строка 2
>   FORMAT не является известным имя встроенной функции."

Скажите в чём может быть дело? Использую MS SQL 2008R2, Windows7.

Comment: В приведенной Вами ссылке написано что необходимая функция доступна начиная с версии mssql 2012

Comment: Спасибо Bald, сам виноват. А аналогичные функции в более ранних версиях присутствуют?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как написал пользователь Bald функция [FORMAT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh213505.aspx) доступна начиная с версии **SQL SERVER 2012**.

В более ранних вы можете использовать так:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12) , @d , 3)
```

Результат:

```
01/10/11
```

[Для справки](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать))